# Smallest/Largest float or double precision constant in OpenCL

Tags: opencl

I need the smallest/largest floating point number in an OpenCL kernel program which involves computing log probability. I had a look on OpenCL reference manual but I cannot locate such constants.

In Java it is equivalent to something like Double.MAX_VALUE;

In C it is in float.h

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are called FLT_MAX / FLT_MIN, and DBL_MAX / DBL_MIN.
See [Macros and Limits](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/macroLimits.html) in the OpenCL 1.2 spec.

Answer (score 0):

Well one obvious solution is to just use 1E+37. But it would be good to know if OpenCL has already defined such constants.